# size of text area

Tags: c, gcc, memory-layout

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

When i run the following commands:

```
gcc memory-layout.c -o memory-layout    
size memory-layout
```

I get the output as:

```
text       data        bss        dec        hex     filename    
960        248         8          1216       4c0     memory-layout
```

As text area contains the executable instructions of a program, why the output is showing size of text area as 960, which is too big with respect to the size of the instructions, as far as I can count.

Comment: This article may be of some interest to you: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html.

Comment: I would argue that returning `0` is a bit sloppy, I recommend `#include <stdlib.h>` and then returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`. See how much better that communicates the intent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is probably because the *actual* start of a program isn't really the `main` function, but a piece of code added in the linking stage. This code setup the libraries, clears the `BSS` segment, and other initialization before calling your `main` function. There is also code to make sure that everything is cleaned up properly when you return from `main`.

Comment: Got it.. Can you also clear one more doubt, What is the exact use of the return statement inside main? In older version compilers[x86], it is not necessary. For what purpose, it has been included in the later version compilers? I have heard that it tells the OS that the program has been executed successfully. Then why only 0,why not any other integer? Is there any other reason apart from this?

Comment: @algogeek The `return` in `main` is needed because `main` is declared as returning an `int`, it's in the standard. And you can return any integer you want, it's just that zero has historically meant that all is okay, while a positive value is an indicator of failure. It's actually this returned value that is the error code in a shell when a program is executed as a command.

Comment: @algogeek: the `return` statement in `main` provides an exit code for the program. If you're running under an OS this value can be reported to whoever started your program. Starting from C99, the return statement is optional, and if execution reaches the end of `main` then behavior is defined to be the same as if you returned `0`.